# How to locate spring dependencies

Tags: eclipse, spring, dependency-injection

I am debugging a large application built with spring using eclipse. What are some good strategies to find autowired dependencies between classes? Currently, I look for the appcontext.xml file closest to the part of the code I am currently in. Usually, I find a base package there which I use to look for the class. Sometimes, I find an interface in that package. I then copy over the name of that interface and search for something like "implements <>". Is there a shorter approach to do this in eclipse which I am unaware of?

Thanks

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: maven dependencies ? I see you added dependency-injection tag, do you mean "dependencies between classes in your design" ? As @dunni puts it, can you be more specific ?

Comment: Thanks, dunni, Alex - have edited the question to make it more specific.